# Add CSS for img inside div > a

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML markup that is produced by a third party system and I can add custom CSS

```
<div class="large-header__logo">

<a href="https://www.integra.im" class="flex w-full h-full">
<img src="" alt="" class="max-h-12 max-w-40 object-contain ">
</a>
</div>
```

I want to make the image larger.

I tried adding

```
.large-header__logo a img { }

.large-header__logo > a > img { }

div.large-header__logo a img { }

div.large-header__logo > a > img { }
```

But none of them worked

Comment: There can so many reasons for it to not work. It's very difficult to say with what you have shared. Do you have styles applied on `<a>`? Are those working?

Comment: Agree with comment above. Could also try attribute selector: `img[class="max-h-12 max-w-40 object-contain "] { }`

Comment: Agreed with above comments. Just adding if styles are preset by the third party system you could use !important to override them, eg. `.large-header__logo a img {width:800px !important;}`

Comment: You don't need `a` in the middle if you use spaces. See [the Descendant Combinator in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator). Just do `.large-header__logo img { }`

Comment: @Rojo . . . Doesn't it? If you do specify the `a` in the CSS selector, does the style definition also get applied to the image in this HTML fragment: `<div class="large-header__logo"><img></div>` (without using an anchor around the image)???

Comment: @BartHofland Yeah it does but I'm assuming that doesn't exist. OP's way is safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are overriding style, it is ok to use `!important`

```
div.large-header__logo a img { width:1000px !important; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are any of the styles within the classes on the img tag overwriting your custom CSS? If so you can try adding !important

```
<img src="" alt="" class="max-h-12 max-w-40 object-contain ">
```